# A subset $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ is compact iff every nested sequence of relatively closed, non-empty subsets of $A$ has non-empty intersection.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-writing, compactness

This is the problem.

Let $A\subset\mathbb R^n$. I want to show that $A$ is compact if and only if every nested sequence $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of relatively closed, non-empty subsets of $A$ has non-empty intersection.

I know how to prove "$\Rightarrow$" direction, using the fact that $A$ has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property, or more simply, using a theorem relating the compactness and the finite intersection property.

But I am not sure how to prove "$\Leftarrow$". I tried the following. I assume that $A$ is not compact, so $A$ does not have the Bolzano-Weierstrass proprty. So there is an infinite subset $B$ which does not have a limit point in $A$. So there exists a collection of open sets $\{O_x\}_{x\in B}$ such that

$$O_x\cap B=\{x\}$$

for all $x\in B$. Then one can find a countable subset $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\subset B$, and the corresponding collection of open sets $\{O_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ with $O_i\cap B=\{x_i\}$. Further more, one constructs a sequence of relatively closed, non-empty subsets

$$A_n=A-\cup_{i=1}^nO_i$$.

$\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a nested sequence. So $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\ne\emptyset$. But

$$\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\cap_{n=1}^\infty(A-\cup_{i=1}^nO_i)=A-\cup_{n=1}^\infty O_n$$

which is surely non-empty, in general, since $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is generally a proper subset of $B$.

I cannot find any contradiction. Please help me out!

---

After searching online, I found out that it may be useful to use the property of being sequentially compact, etc.. But I am reading Fred H. Croom's Principles of Topology, which does not discuss it. Please use some different methods.

Comment: BTW: your proof of the existence of $\{x_i\}$ is the proof that relates compactness to sequential compactness. So in a sense, you already supplied the "missing piece" that you mused about in the final comment of your question.

Comment: @WillieWong Unfortuntely, I did not prove the existence of $\{x_i\}$ but I found it natural to have such $\{x_i\}$ because one can always label some points in $B$, at least in $\mathbb R^n$. So from your comment, it is possible that there does not exist such kind countable subset for an infinite set in a generic metric space or even a generic topological space. Right?

Comment: I see, I misread your argument. In a metric space pretty much all notions of compactness are equivalent. So if $A$ were not compact, you will be able to find a sequence of points in $A$ which does not converge in $A$.

Comment: And yes, in general topological spaces the equivalence can fail. A set $A$ which is non-compact but for which every nested _sequence_ $A_n$ ... holds is the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)). You can rescue things by changing the index set from the naturals to arbitrary directed sets (essentially doing the "net" construction).

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for your comments. I think I need more time to learn and digest your comments. But I just want to confirm that there always exists a countable subset of an infinite set. The existence should not depend on the topology of the space. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You've successfully found a countable collection of points $\{x_i\}\subset B \subset A$ such that $\{x_i\}$ has no limit points in $A$.

Now let $C_j = \{x_i\}_{i = j}^\infty$.

- Why are the $C_j$ nested?
- Why are the $C_j$ relatively closed?
- What's the intersection $\cap C_j$?

Comment: Wow... it is so simple! Thanks!

Comment: $\cap C_j$ should be empty, inituitively. But I want to prove it. One way to do so is to assume that $\cap C_j\ne\emptyset$, then there is $x\in\cap C_j$, and $x$ should be one of $x_j$'s. Say $x=x_m$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$. Then $x\notin C_{m+1}$, so $x\notin\cap C_j$. So $\cap C_j=\emptyset$. Is this OK?

Comment: @DrakeMarquis: yes. I would however forgo the double negative. "If $y\in C_1$, then $y = x_i$ for some $i \geq 1$. But then $y \not\in C_{i+1}$, hence $y\not\in \cap C_j$." No need to "assume for contradiction."

Comment: This is very nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be a family of subsets of $X.$ We say that $F$ has the Finite Intersection Property (F.I.P.) iff (i) $F\ne \emptyset,$  and (ii) $\;\cap G\ne \emptyset$ whenever $G$ is a finite non-empty subset of $F.$

Theorem: A space $X$ is compact iff $\cap F\ne \emptyset$ for every family $F$ of closed sets such that $F$ has the F.I.P.

Proof: (1). If $X$ is not compact,let $C$ be an open cover of $X$ with no finite sub-cover. Let $F=\{X\backslash c: c\in C\}.$ Then  $F$ is a family of closed sets and $F$ has the F.I.P. but $\cap F=\emptyset.$

(2). If $F$ is a family of closed sets and $F$ has the F.I.P. but $\cap F$ is empty then $\{X\backslash f: f\in F\}$ is an open cover of $X$ with no finite sub-cover, so $X$ is not compact.

Comment: But your theorem only applies to the question the OP asked in one direction, as far as I can tell. (And the OP stated that he used this result in his question.) The condition that every nested sequence of nonempty closed subsets have non-trivial intersection does not imply F.I.P.